# Can a non-standard library avoid data race in standard C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this example:

```cpp
bool lock();  // provided by system
bool unlock(); // provided by system
static int v = 0;
//thread 1
void invoke(){
   lock();
   v = 1;  // #1
   unlock();
}
// thread 2
void invoke2(){
   lock();
   v = 2;  // #2
   unlock()
}
```

Suppose `lock` and `unlock` is the `mutex` provided by the system, they will prevent `#1` and `#2` from producing a data race if they can establish a happen-before relationship. However, [intro.races] p10 says

> An evaluation A happens before an evaluation B (or, equivalently, B happens after A) if:
>
> > - A is sequenced before B, or
> > - A inter-thread happens before B.

For evaluations in two threads, we expect the synchronous to establish the "happen-before" relationship. However, synchronous is defined for the standard library, such as some atomic operations or `std::mutex`. The standard didn't define synchronous concepts for other non-standard libraries. Hence, in the perspective of C++ standard, we do not get synchronous when using `lock()` and `unlock` even though it is provided by the system.

That is, only the standard library can be synchronous because the standard explicitly says so? Depending on the non-standard library will result in UB even though the library is provided by the system and the document of the API says it can avoid data race.

Comment: Why do you ask? It doesn't matter what the standard says, because the third-party library calls should be opaque to the optimizer, so nothing will be reordered across them.

Comment: Dataraces can be very tricky to avoid. Even with a mutex there is no guarantee that thread1 will run before thread2. The only real option is to put functions in a queue and let one other thread execute them one by one (executor pattern).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "because the third-party library calls should be opaque to the optimizer, so nothing will be reordered across them.＂ The standard does not say anything about reordering. It just define happen-before, the things I'm not sure is whether synchronization can specified by other document other than C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

> The standard didn't define synchronous concepts for other non-standard libraries.

The entry "A is sequenced before B" carries a lot of weight here, because that means you can have "A inter-thread happens before B, B is sequenced before C, C is sequenced before Z", and thus can safely conclude "A happens before Z". *happens before* is a transitive relation.

There are two reasonable possibilities that allow a third party library to provide similar synchronisation guarantees to `std::mutex`:

- the third party library (transitively) uses something defined in `std`, and so the standard *does* define that it does synchronise.
- the third party library (transitively) uses something defined by the implementation, which the implementation defines as something that synchronises.

The synchronisation in `lock()` and `unlock()` means that one thread's `unlock()` must *Inter-thread happens-before* the other thread's `lock()`. Each `lock()` is *sequenced before* each assignment, and they are *sequenced before* each `unlock()`. Those together mean that one assignment *happens before* the other assignment, and there is no data race.

An implementation is free to make such guarantees, and still be conformant, because "behaving consistently in a documented manner" is a subset of "undefined behaviour"

Comment: "A inter-thread happens before B, B is sequenced before C, C is sequenced before Z" Across two threads, A must synchronizes with B, however the standard did not say A has synchronization with B, do you mean synchronization is not the concept defined in the standard, it can be specified by other implementation?

Comment: @xmh0511 See edit. The fact that `lock()` and `unlock()` are defined to synchronise means that there is a *happens before* relationship between the assignments, i.e. no data race. There is a chain of *happens before*s that you have to follow, you don't just give up if they are not adjacent

Answer (score 0):

You're vastly overthinking this.

> Suppose `lock` and `unlock` is the mutex provided by the system

Then they behave as specified in your implementation's documentation.

It doesn't matter what the standard says about this. Maybe it has a clause along the lines of "implementations are free to add their own headers with implementation-defined functions", maybe not. It doesn't matter, since all implementations do this anyway.

In practice, the synchronization properties of a specific function call boil down to two things:

- What instructions it calls.
- Optimizer must know that it can't reorder instructions across this call (some instructions; in certain direction).

  Since you're calling an opaque function, the optimizer has to assume the worst and not reorder anything across it.

Comment: However, across two threads to avoid data race, we should establish "happens-before", which is not only the "sequenced-before" in a single thread. Between two threads, "synchronize with" can produce "happen-before", which is defined by the standard, So I am asking, can any other implementation/document specify "synchronize with"? In other words, does the C++ standard grants other implementation define "synchronize with"?

Comment: @xmh0511 *"does the C++ standard grants other implementation"* Implementations can do whatever they want, it doesn't matter if the standard "grants" them a permission or not. Let's say it turns out it doesn't grant the permission, then what? Are you going to stop using those system functions just because of this?

Comment: *Let's say it turns out it doesn't grant the permission, then what? Are you going to stop using those system functions just because of this?* From the perspective of language-lawyer, the answer is yes because it will result in UB.

Comment: I think what I am trying to ask does not clearly express in this post. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762185/is-synchronization-a-internal-concept-of-c-standard. What I am asking is whether two operations synchronized can only be specified by the C++ standard.

Comment: @xmh0511 I'm not asking "From the perspective of language-lawyer". The standard is only useful to estabilish understanding between programmers (including developers of your compiler), trying to laguage-lawyer beyond that point just wastes time. We all know that system-provided synchronization functions do estabilish happens-before for all practical purposes. If you observe them not doing that in practice, you should report a bug to your compiler's developers.

Comment: Do you mean the standard does not impose the limition that "it is forbidden for anyone but the standard to use the phrase 'synchornizes with'". If the system-provided operations has synchronization, then it is the case specified by the definition of "happens-before"?

Comment: @xmh0511 Again, it doesn't matter what the standard says, the implementation-defined functions do estabilish happens-before for all practical purposes.

Comment: The standard does not leave any room that "happens-before" can be implementation-defined. Notice that undefined behavior is not implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @xmh0511 We're talking about different things, and I still can't this idea across to you. If language-lawyering doesn't affect your decisionmaking, why do it? This is what I don't understand. The answer to your question won't affect how you write code, you're going to use those system functions regardless.

Comment: HolyBlackCat So, this question is not about how we actually do in practise, it's about how construe the "synchronize with"