# Is synchronization a internal concept of C++ standard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

Besides these operations defined in the C++ standard that has synchronizations semantic, which can establish "happens before" as per [intro.races] p10

> An evaluation A happens before an evaluation B (or, equivalently, B happens after A) if:
>
> > - [...]
> > - A inter-thread happens before B.

> An evaluation A inter-thread happens before an evaluation B if
>
> > - A synchronizes with B, or

That is, across two threads, `A` happens before `B` if `A` synchronizes with `B`. However, is synchronization is a internal concept that is only defined for C++ standard? Or, is it a openning concept that can be defined by other documents(e.g. implementation documents) outside of the C++ standard? **In other words, does the C++ standard grants other document/platform or third-library define the synchronization relationship such that they further have happens-before relationship?**

What I am asking is whether third-library can specify the synchronization for a paired operations such that they would have happen-before relationship according to the definition above? For example, in certain platform, it provides the `lock` and `unlock` which is not the infrastructure of C++ standard library, however, we need use them to prevent data race on that platform, however avoid data race depends on whether they can establish happens-before relationship. If the synchronization is a internal concept of C++ standard, it will mean we cannot use any third-library.

Comment: The standard can't really — and doesn't try to — prevent specific C++ implementations from making additional guarantees beyond what the standard requires. But third-party libraries? How could a library provide a guarantee without relying on the guarantees provided by the implementation?

Comment: BTW, you may find this relevant: ["Threads Cannot be Implemented as a Library"](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-209.pdf), Hans-J. Boehm, 2004.

Comment: *"does the C++ standard grants other document/platform or third-library define the synchronization relationship such that they further have happens-before relationship?"* -- I'm having trouble parsing this. Which "synchronization relationship"? What does "they" refer to? (When I guess at the answer to one of these, the other makes no sense. It's like some key words are missing.)

Comment: *"a internal concept that is only defined for C++ standard"* -- I don't get what you are trying to describe. In one sense, the C++ standard itself is only defined for the C++ standard. Are you asking if the C++ standard contains something like *"it is forbidden for anyone but the standard to use the phrase 'synchornizes with'"?*

Comment: @JaMiT I meant can third-library implementation specify synchronization for a paired operations? In other words, the third-library provides `lock` and `unlock` functions, which is not the standard library infrastructure. In other words, saying two operations are synchronization **can only be defined by the C++ standard**?

Comment: @JaMiT *Are you asking if the C++ standard contains something like "it is forbidden for anyone but the standard to use the phrase 'synchornizes with'"?* Yes, It is what I am asking. In other words, C++ standard does not admit the other 'synchronizes with' except those defined in c++ standard library, if it is, it appears to me we cannot use platform infrastructure to establish happen-before relationship and using non-c++-standard library must cause UB.

Comment: @xmh0511 No, the C++ standard does not have a copyright/patent/trademark/etc. on the phrase "synchornizes with". There is nothing blocking anyone from using that phrase with whatever meaning is desired in whatever context is desired. *I think I'm still missing part of the intended meaning, since I don't see why this question would even come up.*

Comment: @JaMiT the *C++ standard does not have a copyright/patent/trademark/etc. on the phrase "synchornizes with"* I think you misunderstand my meaning. What I meant is that, Does the C++ standard give the room to implemnetations to define which operation synchronizes with another operation? The opposite is, all operations that synchronize are all defined by the standard and there are no other operations that can be defined "synchronize with" in terms of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Adding *synchronizes-with* edges to a program’s semantics can only reduce the set of potential executions, so the **implementation** can add as many of those as it likes in the course of selecting one such potential execution for the purposes of [intro.abstract]/6.2.  An arbitrary library recruited by the programmer does not have such authority, any more than it can employ words of power like “have no undefined behavior” ([atomics.types.float]/8).

It is of course up to the implementation to **specify** whether a library is part of that implementation such that it might be able to do things like synchronization; an implementation that so blessed a mechanism that it did not actually honor in its optimizations would simply be non-conforming.

Comment: The current standard doesn't grant implementation to define which library can synchronize with another library called in other threads, at least, I didn't find the wording that looks something like: other synchronization operation is implementation-defined.

Comment: @xmh0511 Because a data race is undefined behaviour, an implementation is able to act as-if it blessed certain functions with synchronisation. "Acting consistenly in a documented manner" satisfies the empty set of requirements.

Comment: @Caleth You seem to claim that using the synchronization infrastructure provided by implementation results in data race, and hence is UB?

Comment: @xmh0511 no, I'm saying that the standard *can't forbid* the implementation from specifying that particular functions synchronise, because it imposes no restrictions on undefined behaviour

Comment: @Caleth Why do you say this is undefined behavior?

Comment: From the standard's POV, it is undefined behaviour. However, the standard can't forbid the implementation from defining behaviour in cases where the standard says it is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256489/discussion-between-caleth-and-xmh0511).