# Is the use of platform-provided synchronous operations a kind of UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, atomic, synchronous

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>     
#include <thread>
int main(){
  pthread_mutex_t mut;
  if (pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL) != 0){
     return 0;
  }
  int a = 0; 
  auto t1 = std::thread([&](){
     for(int c = 0; c<=10000;c++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        a += 1;  //#1 suppose this non-atomic object is protected by the mutex
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
     }
  });
  auto t2 = std::thread([&](){
     int r = 0;
     for(;;){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        r = a;
        std::cout<< a <<std::endl;  //#2 suppose this non-atomic object is protected by the mutex
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        if(r>=10000){
           return;
        }
     }
  });
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```

According to [[intro.races] p10](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#10)

> An evaluation A happens before an evaluation B (or, equivalently, B happens after A) if:
>
> > - [...]
> > - A inter-thread happens before B.

[[intro.races] p9](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#9)

> An evaluation A inter-thread happens before an evaluation B if
>
> > - A **synchronizes with** B, or
> > - [...]

and [[intro.races] p21](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21)

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and **neither happens before the other**, except for the special case for signal handlers described below.
> **Any such data race results in undefined behavior**.

does this code use the feature guaranteed by the implementation **but it is UB in C++ standard**?

#### UPDATE:

Previous content cannot reveal why this code is UB. The updated part gives my explanation: First, `#1` is a modification to a non-atomic object, and `#2` is the read to this object, and they occur in different threads, they do not have data race **if and only if one operation happens before the other**, in short, it means the operations `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut)` in `t1` must synchronize with `pthread_mutex_lock(&mut)` in `t2` such that `#1` happens before `#2`, or vice versa.

However, the C++ standard does not say the operation `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut)` can synchronize with the operation `pthread_mutex_lock(&mut)`, hence [intro.races] p21 is violated, which result in UB.

#### Claim

I don't know why this question is marked as a duplication of "Unspecified, Undefined vs. Implementation-defined". **First, by looking at the comments, this question has a debate point of whether the code is undefined**. Second, this question is not about the difference between UB, unspecified, and implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Implementations define the behaviour of the features they provide (when used correctly).  In terms of whether an optimizing compiler could break anything, it has to assume that the non-inline `pthread_mutex_lock` / `unlock` functions might contain synchronization operations.  Which in fact they do.  The fact that ISO C++ doesn't define the behaviour of something doesn't prevent an implementation from defining it.

Comment: @PeterCordes So, this is a kind of using UB in the view of the C++ standard.

Comment: Side note : Why do you even use pthread_mutexes? Use C++'s std::mutex and std::scoped_lock, manual unlocking  is going to be a bug at some point.

Comment: No, the ISO C++ standard can't override an implementation's ability to define the behaviour of its extensions.  Especially pthread which is just a library, not actual language extension needed.  In C++ terms, the library functions work as if they were implemented with `std::mutex` and/or `std::atomic`, regardless of what their actual internals are.  (Of course it's actually the other way around, `std::mutex` and `std::thread` are wrappers around pthread functions on systems that use pthreads.  But my point is there isn't any behaviour here that couldn't be explained as a pure-C++ library.)

Comment: why would it be UB ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Ah, Socratic question, wd

Comment: @PaulSanders I think its an interesting question how threading was possible to be valid c++ before c++11 (not actually what they asked, but close enough to raise my curiosity). But here the actual question is only in the title and the body refers to sections of the standard without including quotes. Its not perfectly clear what "the feature" refers to. I know OP can do better ;)

Comment: My understanding is that the UB rules basically don't apply to the implementation itself, that compiler-writers are free to use whatever knowledge is available in order to make the publicly-facing side behave according to the standard.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Because, there will be a data race if we cannot establish a "happens-before" relationship between the write and read to the non-atomic object as per [intro.races] p21. The "happens-before" relationship across multiple threads needs the application of rule [intro.races p11.2] (https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#11.2), and the synchronous operations in the C++ standard does not cover these platform-provided operations.

Comment: @PeterCordes UB means the standard does not impose requirements (including,  the implementations can make the program behave consistently when in UB). For example, signed overflow is UB in the perspective of C++ standard, however, the specific platform always gives the truncated result. BUT it still is UB in ISO C++.

Comment: If you compile your program with `gcc -fwrapv` which defines the behaviour, then it's well-defined for your program to do `INT_MIN - 1 == INT_MAX`.    That option creates a dialect of C++ where signed overflow has 2's complement wrapping semantics.  (Not just a happens-to-work-in-practice thing.)  But like I said, nothing like that is required for a program to use a library like pthread.  pthread isn't "special" in C++11; the compiler doesn't need to know anything about it.  You could write its functions yourself in pure portable C++11 using std::mutex. It works as if it was written that way.

Comment: (Before C++11, C++ didn't have a thread-aware memory model, so pthread was doing things that weren't standardized by ISO C++, and didn't have rules and restrictions.  My point is that ISO C++11 and later *do* have threads and synchronization as part of the language, so it's not weird if an opaque function call does some synchronization.  A compiler has to expect that, so there's no way it can assume there will be data-race UB.)

Comment: C++ is allowed to reorder things only if is sure that the observable behaviour doesn't change. It cannot deduce such thing when calling external functions. So technically it might be UB (I'm not sure), but realistically there is no risk.

Comment: @freakish This question is not about reordering, and there is no such concept in ISO C++. we just need to use the normal wording to interpret the code.

Comment: @freakish: Good point.  [How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50951011) explains things in those terms, why it can't break.

Comment: @xmh0511 it is about the reordering. The only situation for this code to not be thread-safe is if the order of acquiring/releasing locks can be switched with read/write.

Comment: @freakish The ISO C++ does not have the model called "reordering", for non-atomic objects, we just need to say whether the operations to them have established a "happen-before" relationship.

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762185/is-synchronization-a-internal-concept-of-c-standard/77763484?noredirect=1#comment137094716_77763484) can explain why this code has UB, better than me

Comment: @xmh0511 the only way for "happen-before" to not be satisfied is if the compiler decides to reorder acquire/update/release sequence. Otherwise it is pthread library that guarantees mutual exclusion.

Comment: @freakish Why do you keep using the informal concept "reorder"? The ISO C++ does not say anything about "reorder". This question is tagged with `language-lawyer`, so it would be better to refer to formal provisions in the C++ standard to explain why, I think.

Comment: @xmh0511 I don't know which exactly document you refer to, but of course the C++ standard mentions reorderings multiple times.

Comment: @freakish https://eel.is/c++draft/ is the ISO C++ standard, I suppose your standard refers to "C++ Reference"? C++ Reference is not the ISO C++ standard anyway.

Comment: @xmh0511 funny you say that, the provided link literally says `This is not an ISO publication.`. No, I refer to oficial published C++ documents. Older versions can be found on open-std.org site. The newest standard is not available for free I think.

Comment: @freakish Could you cite the relevant wording in the official published C++ documents here

Comment: @xmh0511 this: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf should be the C++11 standard. Or so I believe. You can search for "reorder" and other stuff. It is a bit time consuming job to address your issue precisely unfortunately. I'll try to do it later. **EDIT:** oh, wait it is a draft as well. Well, maybe you really have to pay for the final version. C++ is such a pain in the a**.

Comment: You need to look at how those functions are implemented. If they use `asm` - [implementation-defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.asm#:asm,implementation-defined). If they use `__asm__` or any other syntax extension - [your program is ill-formed](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro#compliance.general-8). If they're not written in C++ - they're an extension, and since the standard doesn't document them, they are UB. But this is not `language-lawyer`ing at this point, more like language-[hermeneutics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics).

Comment: @freakish All "reording" about multi-threads are all in the note, which is not the formal wording, and the formal wordings does not have difference with mine.

Comment: I think the answer is simple: Whenever something is undefined by the words of the Standard ("anything can happen"), the Implementation can jump in and say, "well, then we make it well-defined in such and such way."

Comment: @HolyBlackCat they're written in C or ASM but not C++, so do you think the use of these operations is UB in C++'s perspective?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai  It would be undefined *by definition in the standard* if there is no specification at all in the C++ standard of the "platform-provided synchronous operations" of interest.   The standard has its own definition of "undefined" as (essentially) meaning "this standard specifies no constraints on what occurs"  (even if there is no statement akin to "xxx is undefined", xxx still gives UB if the standard does not specify any constraints on the behaviour).

Answer (score 5):

It's not UB.  Concurrent access to `int a` doesn't actually happen when the program is executed on any real system with a working implementation of pthreads, because pthread functions prevent that.
They have well-defined externally-visible behaviour, defined by standards other than ISO C++, specifically POSIX.  On all non-buggy implementations that provide these functions, the behaviour is well-defined.

Without declarations/definitions, the program would be ill-formed, diagnostic required, *not UB*<sup>1</sup>.

The key concept here is that when ISO C++ says "otherwise, the behaviour is undefined", that just means that standard doesn't define it.  **It doesn't forbid real C++ implementations from defining the behaviour for more cases<sup>1,2</sup>.**

The existence in the standard of a few ways to create synchronization (including `std::mutex`, `std::atomic`, and `std::thread` creation and .join) also doesn't forbid implementations from defining other ways to create synchronization, such as hand-written asm and/or system calls.  And/or define the behaviour of data races on `volatile` objects and provide fences against compile-time and run-time reordering that work with that.

**C++ is intended to be extensible with platform-specific functions or even language extensions.  The standard explicitly says so: [[intro.compliance.general] /8](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro#compliance.general-8)**; the only restriction is that extensions can't break a program the ISO C++ standard says is well-formed.

---

**If we're talking about this program on a system that doesn't have pthreads at all** (because it only provides things that the ISO C++ standard says it has to), **the program is "ill-formed" and can't run; it won't even reach the point of having data-race UB.**  That's obviously uninteresting; I'm discussing the case of systems that have correct pthreads implementations.  (Also not just stubs with those names that return without doing anything.)

---

**In terms of the C++ abstract machine where `std::mutex` and `std::atomic` are primitive operations,** you could think of pthreads as a third-party library of opaque functions that work as if they used `std::mutex` and/or `std::atomic` internally to implement functions like `pthread_mutex_lock`.  You could actually write functions with similar names and call them this way to produce a thread-safe program, e.g. with `pthread_mutex_t = std::mutex` and `pthread_mutex_lock` as `m->lock()`.

So the pthreads library's externally-visible behaviour isn't "special"; it doesn't do anything you couldn't do in pure ISO C++.  (At least not in the simplest mutex function you're showing here.)

> However, the C++ standard does not say the operation pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut) can synchronize with the operation pthread_mutex_lock(&mut), hence [intro.races] p21 is violated, which result in UB.

If you wrote your own library that creates synchronization between threads (externally having opaque types but internally allocating arrays of `std::atomic` for example), it wouldn't be weird to document the synchronization without mentioning the details of the internal implementation.

The C++ standard doesn't say your functions called `foo` and `bar` can synchronize either, or that the only libraries are the ones documented in the standard!  As mentioned above, ISO C++ explicitly says implementations can provide more library functions.

---

**In actual reality for implementations that have pthreads, those functions are the primitive operations, the building blocks for `std::mutex` and `std::thread`**.  And they often use implementation-specific stuff like [`asm` statements](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.asm#1) or hand-written asm functions.  There is formal documentation for how such extensions work in many implementations, although you might have a hard time finding formal-enough documentation of every step to prove things correct all the way down.  e.g. the way separately-written asm functions interact with C and C++ compiler-generated code is so well-known by compiler devs that it's maybe not all formally specified in terms of memory-model stuff, so there might be some level of "of course it works" if you want to drill down to the internal implementation of a specific libpthread.

`std::atomic` is implemented in terms of first-class language features in mainstream compilers, for example GCC and Clang have [builtin functions like `__atomic_load_n` and `__atomic_exchange_n`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) which compilers know how to inline and understand how they can optimize memory accesses before/after an atomic operation depending on the memory_order parameter.

`pthread_mutex` stuff *could* be implemented using mostly `std::atomic`, but real implementations of pthreads predate C++11 / C11.

For that and other reasons, they often have functions hand-written in asm, the same way `strlen`, `memcmp` and many other standard library functions are on real implementations.  (They implement behaviour as if they were written in C or C++; I don't think the GCC manual explicitly spells out the language-lawyer aspect of calling a function written in asm, because it's so far from thinking in terms of the abstract machine.  GNU C / C++ does define rules for things like `asm("" ::: "memory")` clobbers which are usable as a compiler memory barrier like `std::atomic_signal_fence(seq_cst)`, but [the actual definition](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers) is in terms of a more asm-based memory model of variables in memory having values that match what the abstract machine says they should.)

In terms of implementing the required ordering guarantees, a hand-written asm function is fully opaque to the optimizer, and has to be assumed to do anything like `mutex->lock()`, atomic seq_cst load, store, `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)`, and read + write all globally-reachable objects.

See *[How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951011/how-does-a-mutex-lock-and-unlock-functions-prevents-cpu-reordering)* for why being non-inline is sufficient.  If you defined `pthread_mutex_lock` in a header so it could inline, you'd write it with sufficient ordering baked in using `__atomic` / `std::atomic`, or GNU C inline `asm` statements, using low-level implementation-defined behaviour to achieve the necessary high-level ordering compatible with how this implementation treats atomics and memory ordering in general.

The internal implementation for any given target ISA using inline or stand-alone asm will creates synchronization on that ISA according to the hardware memory-order rules, perhaps using asm fence instructions or acquire loads / release stores, to be at least as strong as what ISO C++ requires.  Perhaps stronger if the ISA doesn't have a way to do just `acquire` RMWs and `release` stores, like x86 where any atomic RMW has to be a full barrier (`lock cmpxchg` for example).   Combined with the rules the implementation defines for asm, this can create high-level ordering.

---

##### Footnote 1: a missing definition isn't UB, it's an ill-formed program

http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#general-1

> The set of diagnosable rules consists of all syntactic and semantic rules in this document except for those rules containing an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are described as resulting in “undefined behavior”.

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#general-1

> Unless otherwise specified, the program is ill-formed if no declarations are found.

So a warning or error is required for a call to an undefined function. I guess if an implementation wanted to, it could "try" to run an ill-formed program anyway after warning about it, with no guarantees about behaviour?  But then we're outside of C++ land.  To silently break this code, an implementation would have to provide a definition of `pthread_mutex_lock` which didn't actually do locking.

(Or a `pthread_mutex_lock` that's incompatible with the cores that `std::thread` runs the program across?  It's only guaranteed by POSIX to work for threads started by `pthread_create`, and I guess it's hypothetically possible to have a system where one thread-creation method runs threads across a set of cores that requires one flavour of asm instructions for correct locking, which doesn't work for threads created with a different interface.)

http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.undefined - definition of UB

> behavior for which this document imposes no requirements
>
> [Note 1: Undefined behavior may be expected when this document omits any explicit definition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data. Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message ([defns.diagnostic])), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message). **Many erroneous program constructs do not engender undefined behavior; they are required to be diagnosed.** Evaluation of a constant expression ([expr.const]) never exhibits behavior explicitly specified as undefined in [intro] through [cpp]. — end note]

So it's not UB to use these functions on a system that doesn't have them at all, it's just an ill-formed program.

Also note how the definition explicitly grants implementations permission to define whatever behaviour they want to define, which ISO C++ leaves undefined, as in the next footnote.  *In a documented manner* implies that this includes things suitable for production use on those implementations.

##### Footnote 2: defining more behaviour

For example, GCC language extensions such as `typedef uint32_t aliasing_u32 __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias))` let you deref an `aliasing_u32*` pointing at any object without regard for the normal aliasing rules, the same way you can with `unsigned char`.  Also without regard for the normal alignment rules.

Another example is compiling with `g++ -fwrapv`.  `g++ -fwrapv` is a C++ implementation that defines the behaviour of signed integer overflow ([as 2's complement wraparound](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fwrapv)).  Not just as the result you happen to get from UB, but truly well-defined so the optimizer has to respect it.  And `-fwrapv -fsanitize=undefined` won't check for signed-integer overflow.

Such code would or could encounter undefined behaviour if compiled with an implementation that only defined the bare minimum that ISO C++ requires it to define, but not on the implementations they're written for.

ISO C++ overrule the ability of an implementation to define behaviour of various operations, including inline asm, separately-compiled asm, and language extensions like GNU C `__atomic`.

Comment: See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77798143/is-the-use-of-platform-provided-synchronous-operations-a-kind-of-ub?noredirect=1#comment137153163_77798143): *If they're not written in C++ - they're an extension, and since the standard doesn't document them, they are UB.* Presumably, `pthread*` is written in C or ASM but not C++. Implementation of course can define the behavior that is specified as UB in C++.

Comment: @xmh0511: I disagree with the way HolyBlackCat phrased that.  ISO C++ doesn't define the behaviour of `pthread_mutex_lock`, but it doesn't stop the POSIX standard from defining the behaviour.  I finished editing my answer, BTW; I included a paragraph about implementations that don't even have a `pthread.h` or the functions: the program would be ill-formed and wouldn't compile so it couldn't even start running, and couldn't encounter data-race UB.  You could maybe say it has a different kind of UB from trying to call a function that doesn't exist, but I hope that's not what you're asking.

Comment: I could understand you. By reading your answers, I think you seem to agree this behavior should be classified as **implementation-defined behavior**, I tried to clarify it through CWG, see https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/484, however, the other people think this is just UB.

Comment: @xmh0511: In C++ standardese, "implementation-defined behaviour" is stuff that the ISO standard *requires* implementations to define one way or another, such as right shift of a negative signed `int`.  C++ doesn't define the behaviour (or even the possibility) of a program composed of some C++ and some hand-written asm.  It is a valid implementation strategy for the high-level behaviour of a function like `memcpy`, though.  The C++ standard (or POSIX for `pthread` functions) defines what the behaviour needs to be, a hand-written function can implement that behaviour.

Comment: @xmh0511: It seems to me like you're looking for problems where none exist, and every time someone says anything is UB, you assume they're agreeing with you that there's some kind of problem in the standard wording.   [intro.compliance.general] /8 explicitly allows implementations to provide libraries that do whatever they want, including synchronization.  Libraries provided as part of a C++ implementation are allowed to have internals that only work on that target system, that's how the C++ abstract machine interacts with the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what meaning and importance you attach to the word "undefined".

A lot of discussions related to undefined behaviour in C++ programs get bogged down in the notion that *implementations* (compilers, libraries, host platforms, etc) actually attach some meaning to constructs that the C++ standard leaves undefined.

**A C++ language pedant's view**

Every C++ standard (whether draft or ratified) quite explicitly defines the meaning of the term "undefined behavior".   For example, the C++20 draft  [N4849](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) specifies the meaning as "behavior for which this document imposes no requirements".

By this definition, any feature (extended language feature, additional library function, etc) provided by an implementation that is not covered by the C++ standard, has undefined behaviour.

This (narrow!) definition means that use of "platform-provided synchronous operations" introduces undefined behaviour.

This view can be quite practically important in some (not all) projects where portability (between compilers, platforms, etc) is a significant requirement.   Avoiding undefined (and mitigating or managing reliance on unspecified or implementation-defined behaviours) is one way to reduce problems when porting code.

**A slightly more liberal view based on other standards or specifications**

A slightly more liberal view would allow for accepting some other standard (other than the C++ standard) or some authoritative specification that specifies those operations.

So, for example, if the operations are described somewhere in the POSIX family of standards, they are not undefined.

Or, if the operations are specified in a hardware reference manual, they are not undefined.

They key here is a *decision to accept* that compliance with the other standard or specification is appropriate (e.g. for purposes of the project at hand).

There is not some blanket rule that makes a standard or specification acceptable.  For example, hardware-specific operations cannot be considered acceptable if there is a requirement for portability to another hardware platform that doesn't support those operations at all (or, worse, supports them but produces different behaviours on some platforms).

**A pragmatic "I just want my program to work as I intend" view**

In (one, of many) pragmatic views, the importance of behaviour being undefined (or not) comes down to needs of a project.   The purpose of avoiding undefined behaviour is ensuring that a program works - regardless of which compiler is used, what compiler settings, what target platform, etc etc.

It is quite possible to be flexible in the face of a requirement that a program (or system) work correctly across multiple target platforms, when built with different compilers, and with minimal platform-specific code.

For example, it might be decided that the code should be translated (compiled, linked, etc) with a C++11 or later compiler, but also accept usage of (some subset of) POSIX-compliant functions.   Such a decision is perfectly reasonable if (sometimes this is a big "if") acceptable quality POSIX-compliant libraries are available on all target platforms.    Then the only things that remain undefined are those that are left undefined (either explicitly, or by omission) by *both* the C++ standard and the POSIX family of standards.    For example, neither C++ nor POSIX standards specify any constraints on program behaviour if a program uses both `std::thread` and `pthread`s, so using both is a more risky acceptance of undefined behaviour (whatever your definition of "undefined").

Whether the decision is to allow use of "platform provided synchronous operations" or not, it is still advisable to verify that the program works *as required*.  This means having suitable test cases to verify correctness, and running those test cases on a representative set of target platforms.

Comment: Good point, a program relying on behaviour that the ISO C++ standard doesn't define is fine, as long as it's guaranteed (not just happens-to-work) on the implementations it's used on.  But that's not how some people phrase it; as in your first section they choose phrasing like "the program has undefined behaviour", which sounds really bad and is what I was arguing against in my answer, for implementations that can even compile and run this code. The OP seemed to think that this being UB must be a defect in the C++ standard's wording.  Interesting approach to parsing the semantics.

Comment: At the end of your first section, though, you talk about portability and not relying on UB.  If `pthread_mutex_lock` exists at all, it works (or someone's playing dirty tricks on you).  As a portability consideration, this is *very* different from writing code like `*(int*)&my_float` which is well-defined on MSVC, and on clang/gcc `-fno-strict-aliasing`, but silently fails on some other implementations.  Noisy failure to even compile because of missing headers and functions with obvious names is the best possible failure mode.  Also, testing can't guarantee no UB, that's the problem with UB!

Comment: (But interesting point that POSIX probably doesn't define the interaction with C++ `std::thread`, so this maybe actually *is* outside what any standard guarantees.  Unless they define interaction with C11 `threads.h` and `thrd_create` which should be compatible with C++.  I don't want to rewrite my answer to back-pedal on that, since the same argument could be made about an example using `pthread_create` to create threads.  Or would those still be C++ threads according to the C++ standard?  Obviously in reality the data-race UB rules apply across threads created with `pthread_create`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes  Your answer is fine - no need to back-pedal.   When we're in the realms of UB, there are more benign/subtle choices that people often miss or misinterpret (e.g. whether to use POSIX or standard C++ features, or questions of compatibility if both are used) and more serious considerations of what happens when code does pointer molestation or relies on particular compiler's behaviour when strict aliasing rules are broken.

Comment: @PeterCordes  (In your first comment) You're right that, if `pthread_mutex_lock` exists, then it (assuming a decent quality library ;-) ) works.   However, there are cases such as a POSIX libraries being optionally installed, some systems partially comply, although many systems do comply with POSIX not all do, etc etc.   My real point is that, if something is undefined by the C++ standard, it is necessary to consciously decide if that is okay (e.g. we'll reuse our old business-logic library that does POSIX function calls, rather than rewriting it)

Answer (score 1):

Echoing what others have said, in the context of ISO C++ alone, the program literally has undefined behavior, in the trivial sense that the ISO C++ standard *does not define* the behavior of `pthread_mutex_lock`.  It doesn't even mention the word!  So technically, a conforming ISO C++ compiler could provide a `pthread_mutex_lock` that was only well-defined with `pthread_create` threads, not `std::thread`.  Or a Deathstation 9000 version that's intentionally UB or accidentally broken, reordering memory accesses around a call to `pthread_mutex_lock()`; but it could also cause the call to summon nasal demons.  If there was no declaration at all, it couldn't do those things without at least warning about an ill-formed program first, and (most likely in real life) would refuse to compile it at all (e.g. "`pthread_mutex_lock` was not declared in this scope").

But while that statement is true, it is a bit silly.  It's like saying that the word "perro" is undefined because it doesn't appear in an English dictionary.  Well, of course not; it isn't an English word at all, but a Spanish word.  You wouldn't normally see it in a sentence that's meant to be English, but rather in Spanish sentences.  And so if you want a definition, you ought to be looking in a Spanish dictionary.  Then you will see a perfectly reasonable definition, that it is a furry mammal with four legs and a tail that is often kept as a pet.

Likewise, you won't see `pthread_mutex_lock` in a program that is honestly meant to be pure ISO C++.  It's not an ISO C++ function, but rather a POSIX one (that's what the `p` stands for after all), so we only expect to see it in POSIX programs, and so we ought to be looking at the POSIX spec.  Or more precisely, [IEEE Std 1003.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/).  So a C++ implementation that provides a broken `pthread_mutex_lock` could be ISO C++ conforming but not POSIX.

Now there's a difficulty in reading the POSIX spec in conjunction with the ISO C or C++ standards, because, while the POSIX system interfaces (i.e. system calls) are described as a C API, the multithreading functions aren't defined using the C11/C++11 formal memory model.  So you won't find an explicit statement like "`pthread_mutex_unlock()` synchronizes-with `pthread_mutex_lock()`", or that one critical section happens-before another, or anything like that.

What you do find is [Section 4.12 of Base Definitions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12), which includes `pthread_mutex_[un]lock` in a list of functions which, in their words, "synchronize memory".  They don't provide a formal definition of that term as far as I can find, so we have to interpret using common sense.  It seems clear that the intention is to say that memory accesses are not reordered around these calls, and translating that into the C++ memory model would tell us that `pthread_mutex_lock` synchronizes with `pthread_mutex_unlock`, providing the appropriate happens-before ordering on the critical sections and avoiding a data race.

There's the other detail that POSIX speaks of threads only as things which are created with `pthread_create` and not with `std::thread::thread()`.  So again, we have to use common sense to interpret.  The ISO C++ `std::thread` is, in context, clearly tailor-made to be a wrapper around system-specific calls such as `pthread_create`, so it's entirely reasonable to assume that the kinds of threads they create have the same behavior.

So in the context of ISO C++ *together with* POSIX, together with reasonable interpretation, the behavior of this program is perfectly well defined.

As we mentioned above, ISO C++ allows for compilers which would reorder memory access around `pthread_mutex_lock` (causing a data race), or make it summon nasal demons, or not compile it at all.  And this presumably is what you are worried about with your question.  But what we see from this discussion is that *such compilers cannot be provided as part of a conforming POSIX implementation*.   A C++ compiler that is usable on a POSIX system must allow `pthread_mutex_lock` to compile, *and* make it behave as the POSIX spec says, *and* not reorder memory accesses around it.

Such a compiler *could* in theory be implemented by special-casing `pthread_mutex_lock` and other function calls defined by POSIX.  But that's impractical, so what's actually done (at least by reasonable C++ compilers that want to be usable on such platforms) is that they don't reorder memory access around *any* function call unless they know precisely what that call does, and can prove that such reordering won't violate *any* relevant standard.  Typically, this means that reordering around a function call only happens in the following cases:

1. The function's source code is visible to the compiler, and consists only of code that provably allows such reordering.  In particular, it must contain no calls to functions which are not themselves visible in the same fashion.
2. The function is one whose behavior is completely specified by ISO C++ or another relevant standard, and for which reordering would not break any rules.

Since `posix_mutex_lock` does not fit either case, the compiler won't reorder around it, and everything just works.

---

Saying that a given program has undefined behavior under ISO C++ is *not* inherently a bad thing.  It is bad in the following contexts:

1. If the program in question is intended to be portable across *all* ISO C++ implementations.
2. If the program is intended to be portable across some subset of ISO C++ implementations, where some or all of them either do not define the behavior, define it inconsistently, or define it as doing something unwanted.

Neither of those apply here.  A program containing `pthread_mutex_lock` cannot possibly be intended to be portable across all ISO C++ implementations, not by anyone with half a brain cell.  It's more likely intended to be portable across POSIX C++ implementations, and as we've said, those implementations *do* consistently define its behavior as doing what we want.

Comment: *So technically, a conforming ISO C++ compiler could reorder memory accesses around a call to pthread_mutex_lock()* - Is that true?  The standard *requires* a diagnostic for some kinds of ill-formed programs.  I thought that would include for calls to undeclared functions.  Maybe an implementation could choose to warn instead of error out, and then generate a nonsense program, like pretend the function had an empty body so it could inline and reorder around it.  Or forget sequencing rules for all functions in general.

Comment: Anyway, point being that only a malicious or broken implementation could compile/run this without a warning and encounter data-race UB during any given execution.  (Actually I double-checked http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21 and data-race UB is defined as *potentially-concurrent conflicting actions*, not dependent on actual timing during a particular execution. The top of my answer is phrased in a way that's hinting at an argument along the lines of "they won't *actually* conflict regardless of whether it's formally called synchronization by ISO C++", but that doesn't technically avoid UB)

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#general-1 - *Unless otherwise specified, the program is ill-formed if no declarations are found.* /  http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.undefined - if UB results in *terminating a translation or execution*, it has to be *(with the issuance of a diagnostic message).*  But other UB behaviours don't necessarily require diagnostics.  It also says *Many erroneous program constructs do not engender undefined behavior; they are required to be diagnosed.* And I'm hoping the calling an undeclared function falls into the latter category.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#general-1 - *The set of diagnosable rules consists of all syntactic and semantic rules in this document except for those rules containing an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are described as resulting in “undefined behavior”.* - failed name lookup is ill-formed, not UB, and it doesn't say "no diagnostic required". **So I think a compliant implementation can't silently ignore a missing pthread.h and lack of declarations for `pthread_mutex_lock`.**  It's ill-formed, diagnostic required. A bad implementation could maybe still run?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Fair point.  I guess I am imagining an implementation which *does* provide a `<pthread.h>` which in turn *does* declare `pthread_mutex_lock`, but with something other than its POSIX semantics.

Comment: I'd suggest editing to say that there'd have to be functions with those names which match the args you pass, but don't do what POSIX says (or aren't compatible with `std::thread`, only `pthread_create`).  And they'd have to be inline or `__attribute__((pure))` for a compiler to actually know it could reorder loads around it.  For people arguing that there's some kind of defect in the C++ standard's wording (like the OP), saying that a compiler could mis-compile their program in a really nasty way seems scary, and like agreeing that their claimed "UB" is a potentially real problem.